# Start screen cleanup

Tags: 8.0

I like to periodically review my Start screen to see if there is anything I should remove or other apps I might want to pin. Typically I do this by un-pinning *everything* and then, starting from a blank screen, pinning just the apps I use most.

Manually removing everything from the Start screen is a bit tedious, and trying to really determine which apps I need there is sometimes even more so. Are there any apps, features, or special techniques that help with Start screen cleanup? I could use something that does one or more of the following:

- Totally clean the Start screen - removing everything.
- Show usage stats and other information for apps, such as:

  - Last time used.
  - Frequency of use.
  - Live tile options.
- Recommend placement or removal of apps and Live tiles based on above information.

Are there apps or features that can help me with this, or any particular techniques I could use to refine my current manual process?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no such app to this day that does any of the things you are looking for- perhaps, it is something you could build :)

Something of a workaround to achieve part of what you need ("Totally clean the Start screen") is to create a restore point with the bare minimum settings you would like and then whenever you feel like refreshing your icons, you can use that restore point. If this interests you, [this tool](http://www.wpcentral.com/how-back-and-restore-your-windows-phone-data) will help you do that.

There is definitely nothing that measures frequency of use- this would be a tricky little metric to measure too as some apps do most of their work as a background process.